# Using the PowerPoint's laser pointer in symbols of plots

Tags: plotting

I am interested in exploiting a symbol that is similar to the PowerPoint's laser pointer in the role of `PlotMarkers`. Is there any idea to create that!?
This symbol is brought here:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Graphics[{{RadialGradientFilling[{Red, White}], Disk[]},
  Red, Annulus[{0, 0}, {3/8, 1/2}]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** We can use the graphics object above to define a function that constructs insets with desired size and color:

```
ClearAll[markerF]
markerF[size_ : .2] := Inset[Graphics[
 {{RadialGradientFilling[{#, White}], Disk[]}, 
  #, EdgeForm[], Annulus[{0, 0}, {3/8, 1/2}]}], 
 #2, Center, Scaled[size]] &;
```

***Example:***

```
lp = ListPlot[List /@ Transpose[{#, #} &@Range[5]], 
  PlotStyle -> "Rainbow", BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15],
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]

Post-process `lp` to replace `Point`s with the desired marker:

```
lp /. {Directive[___, c_?ColorQ, ___], Point[{x_, _}]} :> markerF[][c, x]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing!!! Thanks so much for your answer but my Mathematica does not have `RadialGradientFilling`. Which version has that!!!

Comment: @InzoBabaria the documentation for RaidalGradientFilling says it was introduced in 12.2.

Comment: Why I change the `Annulus[{0, 0}, {3/8, 1/2}]` to for example `Annulus[{0, 0}, {3/8, 1/6}]`, the program runs to a bug!!!

Comment: @InzoBabaria, in `Annulus[center, {innerRadius, outerRadius}]`  we need to have  `innerRadius < outerRadius`. That is, use `Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/6, 3/8}]` instead of `Annulus[{0, 0}, {3/8, 1/6}]`.

Comment: O my God!!! I am not stupid but I made a bad mistake!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
marker = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQY8r.png"] // ImageCrop;

ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {marker, Scaled[0.1]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]